# Global controller for application in Ember Js

Tags: javascript, model-view-controller, ember.js

Tile says it all! How would one create a global controller which would work across an entire ember app? This way I can create actions which work across multiple views!

Thanks.

C

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`ApplicationController` IS that controller. It's already being anonymously created, just extend it and put what you need in it.

However, why do you want to put global actions in a controller? A better place is probably in `ApplicationRoute`

Comment: So if I have a back button which needs to work across every route, how would you advise this is best achieved?

Comment: does it do the same thing as the browser back button, or something different?